# autostart and broadcast (remove alarm)

Tags: android

I've an autostart class. Everything runs perfectly, but from main app when I disable notify and I reboot I've again a notify. alarm.CancelAlarm should not remove al pending alarms?

```
public class AutoStartNuova extends BroadcastReceiver
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {   
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {

Allarme alarm = new Allarme();
            alarm.CancelAlarm(context);
```

AlarmManager:

Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        if(now.after(cal1))